# Specific search and replace with sed

Tags: string, sed

I have the following data in a file:

```
@ARTICLE{Abazajian03,
   year = 2003,
   volume = 203,
   volume = 203,
@ARTICLE{Alexander03,
   year = 2003,
@ARTICLE{Anderson03,
   year = 2003,
@INPROCEEDINGS{Antonucci03,
   year = 2003,
@ARTICLE{Baes03,
   year = 2003,
   year = 2003,
....
```

and want to transform the "names and dates" from e.g. Abazajian03 to Abazajian2003, and Alexander03 to Alexander2003 etc.

This line almost does it, I think sed can do this

```
sed 's/[a-z][A-Z]*03/2003/' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

But takes off the last alpha-charterer in the replacement(!!) e.g. 
@ARTICLE{Abazajia2003,

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk '/^@/{ sub(/03/,"2003") }1' infile.txt
```

The output (for your current input):

```
@ARTICLE{Abazajian2003,
   year = 2017,
   volume = 203,
   volume = 203,
@ARTICLE{Alexander2003,
   year = 2017,
@ARTICLE{Anderson2003,
   year = 2017,
@INPROCEEDINGS{Antonucci2003,
   year = 2017,
@ARTICLE{Baes2003,
   year = 2017,
   year = 2017,
```

Comment: Ahhh, no, not quite. I don't want to willy-nilly add "year = 2017" to this; just change the last two characters in the @ARTICLE from e.g. 03 to 2003.

Comment: @npross, then why did you write *Ideally, I'd like to do all years e.g. circa ~1970 to 2017 in one go* in your question? Update your description

Comment: Because I have a list of @ARTICLES that range from AUTHOR70 to AUTHOR17 and wanted to change them all to AUTHOR1970 to AUTHOR2017. The last line of the question is confusing, I've removed that. But I did think sed, and not awk, was the way to go here.

Comment: Okay, cool. This works, a little clunky since I have to do: awk '/^@/{ sub(/00/,"2000") sub(/01/,"2001") ...  sub(/17/,"2017") }1' infile.txt for all the years, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^@/ {s/\([0-6][0-9]\)/20\1/;s/\([7-9][0-9]\)/19\1/}' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Brief explanation,

- `/^@/`: Process lines matching the regex '^@'
- `s/\([0-6][0-9]\)/20\1/`: substitute '[0-6][0-9]' prefix with '20' and `\1` refers to the corresponding matching embraced by parentheses
- `s/\([7-9][0-9]\)/19\1/`: substitute '[7-9][0-9]' to prefix with '19' and `\1` refers to the corresponding matching embraced by parentheses

Comment: This does look as if it should work, but I'm getting a:                                
   sed: 1: "/^@/ {s/\([0-6][0-9]\)/ ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'
error

Answer (score 0):

Using **sed**

```
sed -r 's/(^@.*)([0-1][0-9],)/\120\2/g; s/(^@.*)([7-9][0-9],)/\119\2/g;'
```

To understand how it works :
We are capturing two groups for each line starting with `@`
For eg. For first line in your input:  One group before `03,` and second `03,` itself. Then we are replacing it with first_group`20`second_group

`[0-1][0-9],` to match years from `00` to `17` to which `20` will be prepended
`[7-9][0-9],` to match years from `70` to `99` to which `19` will be prepended

**Output:**

```
@ARTICLE{Abazajian2003,
   year = 2003,
   volume = 203,
   volume = 203,
@ARTICLE{Alexander2003,
   year = 2003,
@ARTICLE{Anderson2003,
   year = 2003,
@INPROCEEDINGS{Antonucci2003,
   year = 2003,
@ARTICLE{Baes2003,
   year = 2003,
   year = 2003,
```

Comment: This is saying:: sed: illegal option -- r

Comment: @npross seems like you're using BSD sed ... try `-E` instead of `-r` and let me know if it works.